# How can I access the request as HttpRequestBase in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm porting a simple application from ASP.NET MVC to WebForms and I am supposed to  pass a instance of `HttpRequestBase` to a method, but I'm only finding the instance of `HttpRequest`, which is exposed as the property `Request` from the `Page` class.

How can I get an instance of `HttpRequestBase` from a `System.Web.UI.Page`? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `HttpRequestWrapper` instance which will convert from `HttpRequest` to HttpRequestBase.

```
var httpRequestBase = new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpRequest);
```

[MSDN Reference Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper.aspx)